# .htaccess: Point Secondary Domain to Primary's Subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, vps

I have two domains on a VPS server, the primary "domain1.net" and the secondary "domain2.com". The website I have currently set up for domain2.com resides at domain1.net/subd1/subd2. I'm trying to create a rewrite rule for my .htaccess file so that whenever someone visits the site "domain2.com", "domain2.com/index.php", it grabs the page from "domain1.net/subd1/subd2", "domain1.net/subd1/subd2/index.php". I would like to do this while keeping "domain2.com" intact in the web address, instead of moreover redirecting it, and have all images/links appear from domain2.com.

From my understanding, it seems .htaccess's rewrite rule would be able to do such a thing, I just haven't figured out how the syntax would work. However, if there's a superior alternate method, I wouldn't be opposed to hearing it.

I appreciate anyone's help on this issue.